# JAXB marshall & unmarshalling of child element without @XMLRootElement

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am trying to marshall a child element object to get xml string. And then using this xml string I would like to Unmarshall as well.

To clarify, I have generated my jaxb classes from xsd and I don't have any method in ObjectFactory that will provide the desired object.

The xsd defination: IBUSStatusType is a child of root element IBUSMessage

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0" targetNamespace="http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xsd:element name="IBUSMessage" type="tns:IBUSMessage"/>
 <xsd:complexType name="IBUSMessage">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Header" type="tns:IBUSHeaderType"/>
   <xsd:element name="Detail" type="tns:IBUSVariantType"/>
   <xsd:element name="Status" type="tns:IBUSStatusType"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="IBUSHeaderType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Retry" type="tns:RetryType" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="ReplyToStack" type="tns:ReplyToStackType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="TransactionContext" type="tns:TransactionContextType"/>
   <xsd:element name="systemType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="TestEnvironment" type="tns:TestEnvironmentType" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="TransactionSetHeader" type="tns:TransactionHeaderType" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="BeginningSegment" type="tns:TransactionSegmentType" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="LegacySources" type="tns:SourceType" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="Variables" type="tns:IBUSVariantType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="RoutingTable" type="tns:RoutingTableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="OptionalHeaders" type="tns:IBUSVariantType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="TestEnvironmentType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="useStubbedService" type="xsd:string" default="false"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="TransactionContextType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="source" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="actionName" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="serviceName" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="ActionClass" type="tns:ActionClassType" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="MessageType" type="tns:MessageResponseType" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="processDate" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="processTime" type="xsd:time" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="userId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="unitOfWorkId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="operationId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="parentOperationId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="uowGroupIndicator" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="uowGroupSize" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="transactionId" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="responseProtocol" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="aggregation" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="actionType" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="origSource" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="origSourceClass" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="requestIdentifier" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="generatedInterchangeControlNumber" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="generatedGroupControlNumber" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="generatedTransactionControlNumber" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="messageTimeout" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="ServiceVersion" type="tns:VersionType" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="IBUSVersion" type="tns:VersionType" fixed="1.1.0"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <!-- X12 Transactions ONLY -->
 <xsd:complexType name="TransactionHeaderType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="transactionSetIdentifierCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="transactionSetControlNumber" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="conventionReferenceNumber" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <!-- X12 Transactions ONLY -->
 <xsd:complexType name="TransactionSegmentType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="structureCode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="transactionIdentifier" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="transactionSetCreationDate" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="transactionSetCreationTime" type="xsd:time" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="SourceType">
  <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
   <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="action" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="IBUSVariantType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="ReplyToStackType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="ReplyTo" type="tns:ReplyToStackEntry" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="ReplyToStackEntry">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="replyToQ" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="replyToQMgr" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="requestIdentifier" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="IBUSStatusType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="Messages" type="tns:MessagesType" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="MessagesType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Message" type="tns:StatusMessageType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="StatusMessageType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Reason" type="tns:StatusPairType"/>
   <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="FollowUpAction" type="tns:StatusPairType" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="Context" type="tns:StatusPairType" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="StatusPairType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="description" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="code" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="ActionClassType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
   <xsd:enumeration value=""/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="GUI"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="BATCH"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="MessageResponseType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
   <xsd:enumeration value="ServiceRequest"/>
   <xsd:enumeration value="ServiceResponse"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="VersionType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
   <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:complexType name="RoutingTableType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Route" type="tns:RouteType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="RouteType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="key" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="routeOverride" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="routeAppend" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="RetryType">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="count" type="xsd:long" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xsd:element name="delay" type="xsd:long" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I want to marshall an object of IBUSStatusType. To do that my code for marshalling as follows:

```html
  public static StringWriter getStringFromIBUSStatusType(IBUSStatusType iBUSStatusType) throws JAXBException
  {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
        .newInstance(com.myhealth.soa.ibus.v1_1.ObjectFactory.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper",
        new DefaultNamespacePrefixMapper());
    marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
    QName qName = new QName("com.myhealth.soa.ibus.v1_1", "iBUSStatusType");
    JAXBElement<IBUSStatusType> root = new JAXBElement<>(qName, IBUSStatusType.class, iBUSStatusType);
    marshaller.marshal(root, stringWriter);
    return stringWriter;
  }
```

I get this xml string when I do marshall IBUSStatusType object:

```
<ns2:iBUSStatusType xmlns:tns="http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0" xmlns:ns2="com.myhealth.soa.ibus.v1_1"><tns:code>8</tns:code><tns:description>Completed With Warning</tns:description><tns:Messages><tns:Message><tns:Reason><tns:description>Subscriber's email missing</tns:description><tns:code>2187</tns:code></tns:Reason><tns:type>1</tns:type><tns:Context><tns:description>WARN</tns:description><tns:code>Policy=MissingSubscriberEmail</tns:code></tns:Context></tns:Message></tns:Messages></ns2:iBUSStatusType>
```

Well, now I want to Unmarshall this xml string I got from marshal process. And the code for Unmarshall:

```html
  public static com.myhealth.soa.ibus.v1_1.IBUSStatusType getIBUSStatusType(String xml)
      throws JAXBException
  {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
        .newInstance(com.myhealth.soa.ibus.v1_1.ObjectFactory.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();     
    return ((JAXBElement<IBUSStatusType>) jaxbUnmarshaller
        .unmarshal(new StringReader(xml))).getValue();
  }
```

I get this error when I do unmarshall on the generated xml string:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"com.myhealth.soa.ibus.v1_1", local:"iBUSStatusType"). Expected elements are <{http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0}IBUSMessage>
```

Now provided that my namespaces are:

```html
put("http://soa.myhealth.com/common/v1", "cmn");
put("http://soa.myhealth.com/MemberService/v1", "mems");
put("http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0", "tns");
put("http://soa.myhealth.com/member/enrollment/v1", "menr");
```

Comment: Could you share whole xsd with namespaces. It seems you have a target namespace http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0 in IBUSStatusType but when you creating QName qName = new QName("com.myhealth.soa.ibus.v1_1", "iBUSStatusType") in marshalling you use the other one(com.myhealth.soa.ibus.v1_1).

Comment: @lurii I have updated the post with whole xsd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally we made a solution. I am pasting my solution bellow. I did change the code according to @Iurii but the problem was somewhere else.

So, this is the change in Marshalling part. The 2nd paramater of QName must be the class name NOT the object of it. I tried to follow this link https://codenotfound.com/jaxb-marshal-element-missing-xmlrootelement-annotation.html but did not work. When changed the 2nd parameter of QName to Class name then it worked.
And the context should be made out of that class because ObjectFactory does not have it.

```html
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(IBUSStatusType.class);
    
QName qName = new QName("http://soa.independenthealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0", "IBUSStatusType");
    
JAXBElement<IBUSStatusType> root = new JAXBElement<IBUSStatusType>(qName, IBUSStatusType.class, iBUSStatusType);
```

And this is the whole Unmarshal code. We had to change the xml to node before unmarshall it. The import of Element is import org.w3c.dom.Element;

```html
  public static IBUSStatusType getIBUSStatusType(String xml)
      throws JAXBException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException
  {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
        .newInstance(IBUSStatusType.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();    
    
    Element node =  DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder()
        .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()))
        .getDocumentElement();
    
    return ((JAXBElement<IBUSStatusType>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(node, IBUSStatusType.class)).getValue();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just look at your schema

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0" targetNamespace="http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="IBUSMessage" type="tns:IBUSMessage"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="IBUSMessage">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Header" type="tns:IBUSHeaderType"/>
            <xsd:element name="Detail" type="tns:IBUSVariantType"/>
            <xsd:element name="Status" type="tns:IBUSStatusType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

There is a namespace `http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0`
And when you do unmarsalling it expects `http://soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0`
but previously when you do marshalling you put the following namespace

```
QName qName = new QName("com.myhealth.soa.ibus.v1_1", "iBUSStatusType");
```

They are different.

Comment: Good point. I have changed the code to QName qName = new QName("soa.myhealth.com/ibus/v1.1.0", "IBUSStatusType"); but still it did not work